# can not install packages in pip any more in python?

Tags: python

I am having a problem in installing packages in python even though I know the correct command in cmd

```
C:\Users\waleed>pip install pyinstaller
```

But the package is installing until to a point it stop installing and give me an error

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Downloading pyinstaller-4.2.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
     |██                              | 194 kB 4.5 kB/s eta 0:12:37ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\walee\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 437, in _error_catcher
```

I have even tried to turn on turn off the VPN even though my connection is good.

Comment: Is that the whole error message?  It doesn't look like it is, as that message doesn't actually say what is wrong. I don't know how anyone will be able to help you given just the information you've provided, without just throwing out random guesses as to what the problem might be.  There's nothing to go on here.

Comment: Today it worked magically I don't know why.